Validation failed for query for method public abstract util.List
I am new to Spring Data JPA, so I am having a trouble writing queries. I want to get all actors that had role in a certain movie that I get from movieID.
When trying this, I get error while trying to start :

Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List

@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<RoleEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select distinct r.actor from RoleEntity r " +
            "where r.movie.movieID = ?1")
    List<ActorEntity> findByMovieID(Long movieID);

}

Here are my entities:
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "roles")
public class RoleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long roleID;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ActorEntity actor;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private MovieEntity movie;

    private String roleName;

}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="actor")
public class ActorEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long actorID;

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "actor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<RoleEntity> roles = new HashSet<>();

}




@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "movie")
public class MovieEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long movieID;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    private String description;

    @NotEmpty
    private String duration;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDate startTime;

    private LocalDate endTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<RoleEntity> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ProjectEntity> projects = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "movie_genres",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id"))
    private Set<GenreEntity> genres;

}

I tried using native query, but it says it returns Long?!
@Query(value = "select a.id, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.gender " +
        "from actor a " +
        "join roles r on r.actor_id = a.id " +
        "where r.movie_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<ActorEntity> findByMovieID(Long movieID);

Thank you very much in advance!!! :D

You'Re in the RoleEntity repository and want to return a ActorEntity, that's not possible the way you're trying to do. Maybe use the ActorEntity repo, just my 2 cent.

The error will tell you what is wrong with your query, please post the full stacktrace not a snippet.

If you prefer using RoleRepository instead of ActorRepository, you can achieve the desired outcome by querying the entire Role:
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<RoleEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select r from RoleEntity r where r.movie.movieID = ?1")
    List<RoleEntity> findByMovieID(Long movieID);

}

Then, in your service layer, extract the actors from the retrieved roles:
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RoleService {

    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public List<ActorEntity> findActorsByMovieID(Long movieID) {
        List<RoleEntity> roles = roleRepository.findByMovieID(movieID);
        return roles.stream()
                    .map(RoleEntity::getActor)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

